# Identifying pixel colors from image file

Tags: java

How can i check the colors of specific pixels in the image?
The example of what im looking for is map generating from a png file in this  [link](http://www.ludumdare.com/compo/ludum-dare-21/?action=preview&uid=398)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First hit on Google: [Getting and Setting Pixels in a Buffered Image](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.awt.image/ImagePixel.html)

```
// Get a pixel
int rgb = bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y);

// Get all the pixels
int w = bufferedImage.getWidth(null);
int h = bufferedImage.getHeight(null);
int[] rgbs = new int[w*h];
bufferedImage.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, rgbs, 0, w);
```

You can also go through the `bufferedImage.getRaster().getPixel(...)` method.

Answer (score 1):

the solution can be found here : http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-get-example/get-color-of-pixel.shtml